# RecyleView with .kv file (Python/Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Total python newbie question here. Trying to implement a basic RecycleView here but it is not showing up when I run it.  I don't get any errors (outside of a warning stating that I am loading the my.kv file multiple times....I will fix that next)

Any tips on how to get it to run??

I only included code snippets of what is currently being used to try and implement the view.

.py code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder



class TransactionScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

.ky code

```
    TransactionScreen:



<TransactionScreen>:
    name:"transactions"

    viewclass:'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size:None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint:1, None
        size_hint_y:None
        height:self.minimum_height
        orientation:'vertical'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a `RecycleView` in your code. One quick fix is to change:

```
class TransactionScreen(Screen):
```

to:

```
class TransactionScreen(RecycleView):
```

or, perhaps a better approach is to just add a `RecycleView` to the `TransactionScreen`:

```
<TransactionScreen>:
    name:"transactions"

    RecycleView:
        viewclass:'Label'
        data: root.data
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size:None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint:1, None
            size_hint_y:None
            height:self.minimum_height
            orientation:'vertical'
```

and leave the `TransactionScreen` as:

```
class TransactionScreen(Screen):
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something simple.